# How does reply layout appears in android chat app?

Tags: android, layout, chat, reply

I'm creating an android chat. In Telegram Android app, when I touch on reply, a layout appears and I want to how to do the same thing. I tried to the same with an extra constraint layout and make it visible or invisible when necessary.

[image]
What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achived this with add view. By adding constraint layout into Linearlayout. Anyone with better and best practice, please share your answer.

```
LinearLayout item = findViewById(R.id.reply_layout);
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.reply_layout, null);
item.addView(child);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please view types in your adapter. Please see the example https://medium.com/@droidbyme/android-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type-multiple-view-holder-af798458763b